# put JButton on the top of JLabel inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I have JPanel that contains:

JButton and
JLabel with picture set in it

I want to place the button on the top of JLabel in NORTH CENTER position. Currently its set next to each other and I do not know how to overlay JLabel.

I tried many solutions here, however it does not seem to work exactly in a way I wanted. Thanks!

```
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(); // background of the label
picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CoursesGUI.class.getResource("/images/graph_paper.jpg")));
Button en_course_btn = new JButton("English Course");
coursePanel.add(en_course_btn);
coursePanel.add(picLabel);
```

Updated: Button is placed on the top of the JLabel, however not inside.

Comment: Also, never reference the `src` directory in your code, it will not exist at runtime, instead use `Class@getResoruce` and pass it the path of `/images/graph_paper.jpg`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to make image as a background for specific JPanel and then place some buttons. This is my design of the program, and I could make something like this easily in Photoshop using layers, however I am struggling to do the same in java..

Comment: @ Radiodef regarding XY problem, it seems to be similar, however it is not the same  as here is actual code(very specific information), but not essay sentences describing what it is doing. If solution does not work and someone tries to improve their solution, it is not a problem.

Comment: You asked about putting a JButton on top of a JLabel when really you wanted an image as a background (solution is put the button inside the JLabel or use a JPanel). That is an XY problem. So we did not really know what you were trying to do. Also I rolled back your edit, you should not 'update' the code in the question with code from an answer. Doing that makes it confusing for future readers.

Comment: @Radiodef JPanel initially contained JButton and JLabel, hence I wanted to put JButton on top of a JLabel, so it will set image as a background for the buttons, sorry but I cannot upload screenshot to ilustrate what exactly I was meaning, however Thanks for Naruto Biju Mode for understanding my problem and after a few attempts solving it. Btw I will be aware of XY problem too in the future posts. Regarding updating the code, after each iteration, problem may change, hence I was keeping up to date with a current problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set a layout for your label and add your button inside it:

```
JPanel setupPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel coursePanel = new JPanel();

JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(); // background of the label
picLabel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CoursesGUI.class.getResource("/images/graph_paper.jpg")));

// picLabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // sets layout inside the label
JButton en_course_btn = new JButton("English Course");

contentPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
titlePanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

// picLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 470)); // dimensions of inner containers
contentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 670));
titlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 50));

picLabel.add(en_course_btn);
//coursePanel.add(en_course_btn);
coursePanel.add(picLabel);

contentPanel.add(coursePanel); // add coursePanel containing buttons and background
setupPanel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
setupPanel.add(contentPanel);
getContentPane().add(setupPanel);
```

Comment: @ProgLearner try to use the FlowLayout constructor with FlowLayout.CENTER argument (see my updated answer).

Comment: @Natuto Biju Mode , I have uploaded my whole code, hope it may help. The problem after update is the same: I cannot place JButton on the top of JLabel.

Comment: @ProgLearner you should comment the line coursePanel.add(en_course_btn); and add the line picLabel.add(en_course_btn); (see updated code)